# What is filling my phone's RAM, if not apps?

Tags: performance, ram

My Galaxy S3 has gone from snappy to slow over the past few weeks: When I open or change apps it reacts very slowly. When the app is running that app is working fine.

It resembles having too little RAM in your computer: When the program you are using is swapped in, it works just fine, but when you open a new program or switch to a program that is swapped out, it is dead slow.

So I looked into the memory usage of my phone to see if that might be the case:

[image: Memory usage]

It seems my phone is using 750 MB RAM for something it will not tell me.

Others online have suggested the memory is just used for disk cache, but then it would never slow down the phone.

I have rebooted the phone and then the unaccounted usage goes to 500 MB RAM (Is that really the normal RAM usage for a freshly booted phone?), and the phone is much more snappy. That makes me think it is a memory leak.

How can I see what accounts for the memory usage not shown in the "Running Apps" page? How can I release it? If it is a memory leak: Can I add swap so that the leak at least is swapped out?

Android version: 4.3. Baseband version: i9300xxugmk6.

Comment: did you update your phone recently?

Comment: No. I believe last update was before New Year. But even if I had I would still like to know precisely what is taking up the memory: Maybe it is something I can avoid.

Comment: even if you have no applications running in the background at all the phone will still use ram just to use the android core apps which run the phones os and ui.

Comment: may be you can stop using those ram boosters which is pretty much waste for a droid

Comment: The ram booster was installed today to help debug the problem. It is not the cause.

Comment: I know that even if you do not have applications running the phone will still use RAM. What I am asking is: How do I see what the RAM is used for. Maybe it is used for a subsystem, that I do not care about, in which case I might be able to avoid using that. So again: How do I see what the RAM is used for?

Comment: there are plenty of apps in play store to monitor the ram usage eg: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.diagnosis

Comment: This app is great for monitor and diagnosing memory and battery usage: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel. The lite version shows realtime usage, and pro version you can log over a period of time.